# Defining a function though an expression

Tags: plotting, functions

I defined a function called "Funcional" that if we give a function to him it will return a value that depends on $\beta$. Say for example

```
Funcional[Piecewise[{{0, x < 1/2}, {2*x - 3, x > 1/2}}]] = 3$\beta^2 + 16\beta^7$
```

Now I would like to plot this while $\beta$ varies but im guessing Mathematica is not interpreting this result of "Funcional" as a function so how can I do it so it does, my goal is to do this

```
Plot[Funcional[
  Piecewise[{{0, x < 1/2}, {2*x - 3, x > 1/2}}]], {$\beta$, 1/2, 1}]
```

and get the graph in function of $\beta$.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `x`? Why is it there?

Comment: $x$ is there so i can defined a function in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the, way $Funcional$ works is that it is doing some integrals over a region when we give it some function so $x$ is so we have a "function" over the region.

Comment: So, your definition above (`Funcional[...]=...`]) is not actually the definition of `Funcional`. Please edit your question, and include a definition in copyable *Mathematica* code. If you don't know how to do that, click on the circled "?" above the edit window here.

Comment: Can you please post your Mathematica Code so that we can copy and paste it.

Answer (score 1):

What you posted was not syntactically correct *Mathematica* code. Trying to clean it up, define:

```
Funcional[Piecewise[{{0, x < 1/2}, {2*x - 3, x > 1/2}}]] = 3 beta^2 + 16 beta^7
```

Then,

```
Plot[Funcional[Piecewise[{{0, x < 1/2}, {2*x - 3, x > 1/2}}]], {beta, 1/2, 1}]
```

makes a plot.

[image]

But what's happening is not what you think. *Mathematica* is a expression rewriting language. The definition means that when *Mathematica* finds an expression that is an **exact** match to `Funcional[Piecewise[{{0, x < 1/2}, {2*x - 3, x > 1/2}}]]`, it will replace it with `3 beta^2 + 16 beta^7`. And then, of course, you can plot that.

Since you haven't used `_` in your definition, the match needs to be exact. The expression `Piecewise[{{0, x < 1/2}, {2*x - 3, x > 1/2}}]` has to be unevaluated: it's effectively meaningless. It could be any syntactically correct expression that cannot be evaluated. If you give `x` a value, it doesn't work any more.

So, what is it that you're attempting to do here?